# ZFS on Amazon linux ami

Tags: linux-kernel, zfs, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I am trying to install ZFS on my amazon linux ami. Since the package is by default not available in their repository, I downloaded it from http://zfsonlinux.org/ . I also managed to install spl and zfs using their source code.
The kernel package installed are as follows :

```
# sudo rpm -qa |grep kernel
kernel-devel-4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64 
kernel-4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64 
kernel-tools-4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64 
kernel-headers-4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64
```

After install spl and zfs (both version 0.7.5) without any error i tried to use modprobe to load them into kernel. But i got an error.

```
# sudo  modprobe zfs
modprobe: FATAL: Module zfs not found.
```

Also, No logs are generated in dmesg or any other logs. 
Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to install zfs.
Firstly a clean start to the installation process on a new server.
Then i noticed `make install` does not work properly with SPL and ZFS. So manually copy the lib directory to desired location.

Answer (score 0):

try this.on generic linux,after installing packages if you type "zfs list" it says zfs modules not loaded.
"/sbin/modprobe zfs"
verify with 
"dmesg|grep" oder "lsmod|grep  zfs"

Comment: "/sbin/modprobe zfs" gives following error
modprobe: FATAL: Module zfs not found. Also lsmod|grep zfs returns empty response. And "dmesg|grep zfs" is empty but "dmesg|grep zpool" gives
[    6.055268] zswap: default zpool zbud not available

Comment: try reboot.this is how I do on linux.I also try reinstalling "zfs" package.sometimes it does weird things.today  I installed 10 times.I take same steps but get different results with 3 cases.I have no idea what s going.but it works somehow. with dmesg and lsmod zfs is case sensitive btw.

Comment: No. Reboot did not work as well. I reinstalled it once but did not work. Will try that again.

Comment: can you write down how you install zfs? step by step.definitely you couldnt manage to install.did you crosscheck if amazon linux ami is supported?

Answer (score 0):

Install the zfsonlinux yum repository in /etc/yum.repos.d/zfsonlinux.repo:

```
[zfsonlinux]
name=ZFS on Linux repo DKMS
baseurl=http://download.zfsonlinux.org/epel/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
failovermethod=priority
fastestmirror_enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
sslverify=true
```

Install the latest kernel and kernel-devel: `yum install kernel kernel-devel`

Reboot.

Install zfs: `yum install zfs`

Make sure the module you just built is loaded: `modprobe zfs`

Comment: where did you get this repo file from? can I get an updated version from zfsonlinux themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I just went through it on a fresh Amazon Linux AMI launch:

```
yum update -y
sudo rpm -qa |grep kernel
uname -a
yum install -y kernel-headers-4.14.214
yum install -y kernel-devel-4.14.214
yum repolist enabled
yum install -y zlib-devel libuuid-devel
amazon-linux-extras install epel
yum install -y libblkid-devel
yum install -y libcrypto-devel
yum install -y crypto-devel
yum install -y openssl-devel
wget https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/releases/download/zfs-2.0.2/zfs-2.0.2.tar.gz
tar xzvf zfs-2.0.2.tar.gz
cd zfs-2.0.2/
./configure
make -j4
make install
modprobe zfs
lsmod
zpool list
zpool create test sdb
zpool status test
```

It's gotten really easy!